# Blazor route changes in same page

Tags: .net-core, blazor

I'm current setup:

- .NET core 3 (preview 6)
- Blazor server side rendering

In a Blazor page I have something like the following:

```
@page "/page"
@page "/page/{Id}"
```

With:

```
[Parameter]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

Now, when navigating from, for example, `/page/1` to `/page/2`, I can use `OnParametersSetAsync` to detect these changes. But the problem occurs when navigating from `/page/1` to `/page`. `OnParametersSetAsync` can detect this change, however the `Id` parameter will stay as `1` from the previous route.

I was wondering what i could do in this situation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Blazor doesn't override empty parameters with null, do it by yourself:

```
@page "/Counter"
@page "/Counter/{Id}"
<h1>Current Id: @IdString;</h1>
<a href="/Counter"> go home </a> |
<a href="/Counter/1"> go home 1 </a> |
<a href="/Counter/2"> go home 2 </a>

@code
{
    private string IdString;
    [Parameter] public string Id { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        // copy par value somewhere
        IdString = Id?.ToString() ?? "";

        // rest parm (set to null) by yourself
        Id=null;  
    }
}
```

[image]