# How to get the old parameter values in Blazor OnParameterSet?

Tags: blazor

I want to compare old and new parameter values and decide to execute different initializations or logic based on that. How to do in Blazor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> // It's internal because there isn't a known use case for user code
>   comparing
>           // ParameterView instances, and even if there was, it's unlikely it should
>           // use these equality rules which are designed for their effect on rendering.

Source: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Components/Components/src/ParameterView.cs (line 113)

Read the rest of the comment.
Note: ParameterView is the formerly known "object" ParameterCollection.

Now if this feature is essential to you, you should go to github and tell them that:

> It's internal because there isn't a known use case for user code

**is no longer true.**

Of course you can store old values in variables in the OnParametersSetAsync lifecycle method and compared it with new parameter values, but then this is only a hacky work-around, and you should be careful about what you do. Surprises are awaiting you on each corner.

See this if you've got spare time: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/3148acfb105a16aa6c535d00eb0e50ec03992f3f/src/Components/Components/src/RenderTree/RenderTreeDiffBuilder.cs

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can store previous value on var, for example:

```
@page "/Counter"
@page "/Counter/{Id}"
<h1>Old Id: @IdSOld;</h1>
<a href="/Counter"> go home </a> |
<a href="/Counter/1"> go home 1 </a> |
<a href="/Counter/2"> go home 2 </a>

@code
{
    private string IdOld;
    [Parameter] public string Id { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        // copy par value somewhere
        IdOld = Id?.ToString() ?? "";

        // reset parm (set to null) by yourself
        Id=null;  
    }
}
```

See also: [Blazor route changes in same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56869508/blazor-route-changes-in-same-page/56870014)

Comment: Are you sure this works? The id at that point is the new I'd. It certainly doesn't work for components that are not page.